# android get mssql text column to textview as formatted

Tags: android, sql-server, textview

i am sure that there is easy way but i searched and could not find the solution,

i get data from text column of mssql as string, and i want to show data as like shown in column.

I mean my data like

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>
> consectetur adipiscing elit. In condimentum turpis nibh.
>
> Vivamus scelerisque odio sit amet nisi dignissim, at pellentesque ligula dapibus. Nulla et lacinia dolor.
>
> Aenean sed faucibus felis, in molestie tellus.

Bu when i setText to textview it is like;

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In condimentum turpis nibh. Vivamus scelerisque odio sit amet nisi dignissim, at pellentesque ligula dapibus. Nulla et lacinia dolor. Aenean sed faucibus felis, in molestie tellus.

How can i show text as i want in textviev? Thanks for help

Comment: Is there any one who can help? No way to organize text as html

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the text with Html(like inserting paragraph tag) in your server (i.e. in your database)and then receive it in your application.

Then in the text you can set the text as:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml("your text"));
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer bu there is too many data in sql thats way i have no chance to edit text like html.